# Fourier-Series of rectangle function: $f(x) = 1$ if $|x|\le \pi/2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I have to create the Fourier-series of the function:

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$|x| \le π/2 $} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

My approach:

$$a_0=\frac1π\int_{-π}^π f(x) \,dx= \frac2π\int_0^{π/2} 1 \,dx = 1$$

$$a_n=\frac1π\int_{-π}^π f(x) {cos(nx)} \,dx= \frac2π\int_0^{π/2} cos(nx) \,dx = \frac2π \frac{sen(n{π/2})}n  $$

Observing that:

$$ sen(n{π/2}) =
\begin{cases}
(-1)^k,  & \text{if $ n = 2k +1 $} \\
0, & \text{if $ n = 2k$}
\end{cases}$$

Finally;

$$f(x)= \frac12 +\frac2π\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}cos[(2n+1)x]$$

But the correct answer is;

$$f(x)= \frac4π\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}cos[(2n+1)x]$$

Where am I  wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is the correct one.

Notice that $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is within the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ of values unchanged by the Fourier series so should still have its original definition $f(x)=0$. But then the "correct" formula would have
$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\left(2n+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)&=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},&n\equiv 1,2\mod 4
\\
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},&n\equiv 0,3\mod 4\end{cases}
\\
\\
\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n+1}\cos\left(\left(2n+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)
&=\frac{4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\ge 0\\n\equiv 1,2\\\operatorname{mod} 4}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n+1}-\frac{4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\ge 0\\n\equiv 0,3\\\operatorname{mod} 4}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n+1}
\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{8k+1}+\frac{-1}{8k+3}+\frac{1}{8k+5}+\frac{1}{8k+7}\right)
\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-(64k^{2}+64k+13)}{\left(8k+1\right)\left(8k+3\right)\left(8k+5\right)\left(8k+7\right)}
\\
&\le\frac{-4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{64k^{2}}{\left(8k+7\right)^{4}}
\\
&\le\frac{-4}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{64}{8^{4}}\frac{1}{2^{4}k^{2}}=-\frac{\pi}{6}\cdot2^{-\frac{17}{2}}\approx −0.001
\\
&\ne 0
\end{align}$$

which is not $0$. In fact it is $-1$ and their function takes the value of $-1$ where it should be $0$. Assuming you copied down the function correctly, it may just be a mistake in the worksheet.